# Excel VBA InStr very slow and hanging

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below VBA code to compare 60K records (only a particular string) from 'Sheet1' with 7K records from 'Sheet2'. It's taking a very long time to complete and is unresponsive at times. Is there anyway to improve the performance of this subroutine?

```
Sub txtext()

Dim fnl As String, stl As String, env As String, typ As String
Dim ctm As String
Dim stdate As Date, enddate As Date

lr = Sheets("cid_match").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
cr = Sheets("scme").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
stdate = Now
m = 2

For Each e In Sheets("cid_match").Range("BI2:BI" & lr).Cells
stl = Worksheets("cid_match").Range("BI" & m).Cells.Value
typ = Worksheets("cid_match").Range("BK" & m).Cells.Value
s = 2
    For Each r In Sheets("scme").Range("C2:C" & cr).Cells
        ctm = Worksheets("scme").Range("B" & s).Cells.Value
        fnl = r.Value

        If InStr(fnl, stl) > 0 And ctm = typ Then
            Worksheets("cid_match").Range("BJ" & m).Value = fnl
            GoTo sss
        End If
    s = s + 1
    Next r
sss:
m = m + 1
Next e

enddate = Now
MsgBox "Succesfully Completed!!! Started at " & stdate & " Ended at " & enddate

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include pictures of your Worksheets such that we know where and how your data is organized.

Comment: I can't write it up right now but I would say the quickest would be to put it into memory (i.e. read it into an array), do the checking there, the write out the results. Also add `DoEvents` to stop hanging. If someone could write that up you'd be on to a winner I think.

Comment: Per the comment by @GaryEvans, yes the primary issue is working the routine directly within cells.  If memory serves, each use of the Range (or Cell) method is a COM call.  Just moving the data into an array using one COM call would dramatically increase performance.  Have a look here to make that happen: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize searching for a record you want to firstly sort your data using either **quicksort** or **bubblesort**. Then you will be able to search through using **binary search**. This will significantly reduce your wait times. Lucky you, these functions have already been written in VBA by other developers.

**Bubblesort**

```
Sub BubbleSort(list()) 
'   Sorts an array using bubble sort algorithm
    Dim First As Integer, Last As Long 
    Dim i As Long, j As Long 
    Dim Temp As Long 

    First = LBound(list) 
    Last = UBound(list) 
    For i = First To Last - 1 
        For j = i + 1 To Last 
            If list(i) > list(j) Then 
                Temp = list(j) 
                list(j) = list(i) 
                list(i) = Temp 
            End If 
        Next j 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

**Binary Search**

```
Function arrayFind(theArray() As Integer, target As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim low As Integer
    low = 0
    Dim high As Integer
    high = UBound(theArray)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result As Boolean

    Do While low <= high
        i = (low + high) / 2
        If target = theArray(i) Then
            arrayFind = True
            Exit Do
        ElseIf target < theArray(i) Then
            high = (i - 1)
        Else
            low = (i + 1)
        End If
    Loop

    If Not arrayFind Then
        arrayFind = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: where did you find these functions? is there some website with a library of these with some documentation?

Comment: Well the algorithms are very famous. They are known to be the fastest for general cases for sorting and searching. Actually I am wrong, quicksort is faster than bubblesort. The algorithms are on Wikipedia. I typed the name of the algorithm and VBA into Google and found lots of variations of implementation. You can also just write your own.

Comment: and if the arrays are filled with strings instead of numbers ? Good idea but since the OP uses instr(), i don't think it would be very usefull

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier, I am sure the OP would be smart enough to apply the exact same algorithm to Strings which CAN be ordered alphabetically. We are not here to do his work for him, we are here to answer questions. His question pertained to how his search task can be done more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below: -

```
Sub Sample()
Dim AryLookup()     As String
Dim DteStart        As Date
Dim LngCounter      As Long
Dim LngRow          As Long
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet

DteStart = Now

'Look at the lookup worksheet
Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("scme")

    'Make an array the same size as the dataset
    ReDim AryLookup(WkSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    'Copy the dataset in
    For LngRow = 2 To UBound(AryLookup, 1)
        AryLookup(LngRow - 2) = WkSht.Range("C" & LngRow)
        DoEvents
    Next

Set WkSht = Nothing

'Look at the source worksheet
Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("cid_match")

    'Work from the bottom up so not to be falsly stopped by an empty row
    'Step -1 means go backwards by one with each itteration of the loop
    For LngRow = WkSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

        'Look through the loop for a match
        For LngCounter = 0 To UBound(AryLookup, 1)

            'If it matches then add it to the column and exit the loop
            If InStr(1, WkSht.Range("BI" & LngRow), AryLookup(LngCounter)) > 0 Then
                WkSht.Range("BJ" & LngRow).Value = AryLookup(LngCounter)
                Exit For
            End If

            DoEvents
        Next

        DoEvents
    Next
Set WkSht = Nothing

MsgBox "Succesfully Completed!!! " & vbNewLine & "Started at " & DteStart & vbNewLine & "Ended at " & Now

End Sub
```

Looking over your code was quite confusing to follow what was happening, in some cases I couldn't understand or see the benefit in what was happening in the code, so the above *may* not be correct. You should always write your code with the assumption that another developer will need to pick it up and support it one day, it'll help you in the future if you have to return to it years later and want to remember what is happening.

Comment: in fact all those `doevents` will slow down the thing. And you need a second array for the 7k records sheet also, obviously. And to populate the array you do it in a single read, only since it's a column the read from, the first array must be Dimmed as `(1 to WkSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row , 1)`

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Full of the nay-saying there. Be a little more positive and write up your own answer to help the user. My solution works, its quicker than what he had, and DoEvents stop it hanging, answering his questions. If there is a better way we would all like to see your answer as I am not aware of reading a range of cells into an array in one go myself.

Comment: Gary Evans, `Dim arr as Variant <newline>arr = myRange.Value2`